# Changing the navigation Bar color in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, colors, uinavigationcontroller

I am attempting to change the color of my Navigation bar. Attached below are images of my navigation bar at runtime, the storyboard of my app, and lastly the attribute inspector.

[image: Navigation Bar]

[image]

[image: Attribute Inspector]

[image: Document Outline]

I have been through several StackOverflow pages and still can not find a successful way to change the color of my navigation bar. Any changes I make in the attribute inspector are not shown at runtime.

Comment: Try changing background property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 37/255, green: 116/255, blue: 169/255, alpha: 1)
```

Where can I contact this code?

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot.